# CakePHP data not saving and validation not working

Tags: validation, cakephp

When my model goes to validate my form

1. it always come as false,
2. it doesn't save in the database.

I dont understand why this isn't working, it was working until I unbind on a few of my functions.

Here is my invoice model, it's supposed to check if there is to/biller in relationships_users table (relationship model).

```
<?php

class Invoice extends AppModel{ 
    var $name='Invoice'; 
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Relationship' =>array(
            'className' => 'Relationship',
            'foreignKey' =>'relationship_id',
            )
        ); 
    var $validate = array(
        'to' => array(
            'relationshipExists' => array(
                'rule' => array(
                    'relationshipExists'),
                    'message' => 'sorry you dont have a relationship with that user.'
                    ),
        ),          
        );

    public function relationshipExists($check){ 
        $relationshipExists=$this->Relationship->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Relationship.partyone' => current($check),
                'Relationship.partytwo' => current($check)
            // get the value from the passed var
            )
        )
        );
            if ($relationshipExists>0) {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
                return FALSE;
    }
```

Here is my function in the invoices table

```
 public function addinvoice(){
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Invoice');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        ($this->Invoice->set($this->request->data));
        if($this->Invoice->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('to','Invoice.relationshipExists')))){
            $this->Invoice->save($this->request->data); 
            $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice has been saved');  
      }}else { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice could not be saved. Please, try again.');
             }
    }
```

What it's supposed to do is to check that to/biller are in the relationships_users table and then save the invoice to the invoice table, otherwise throw a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions array seems strange to me:

```
        'conditions' => array(
            'Relationship.partyone' => current($check),
            'Relationship.partytwo' => current($check)
        // get the value from the passed var
        )
```

That would search for Relationships with both `partyone` *and* `partytwo` set to `to`. You probably want to check if *either* of them is set to `to`:

```
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                'Relationship.partyone' => current($check),
                'Relationship.partytwo' => current($check)
            )
        // get the value from the passed var
        )
```